# Do you think (if) you could

Tags: sentence-construction, if

> Do you think **if** you could check this essay for me?

Is **if** legitimate in that place, or it is a dish best served without **if**?

Comment: Leave out the _if_. It would be more appropriate in a construct like this: _If you would check this essay for me, I would appreciate it._

Comment: @J.R.: Native speakers seem pretty easily distinguish when **would** is used as a *modal verb* and when as an *auxilliary*.

Comment: I thought this question was about the word _if_. I'm telling you, it should be left out of the sentence you inquired about.

Comment: @J.R.: About if, you're right. I just made a conversational note.

Comment: In a different sentence **if** would be appropriate, for example: *I was wondering **if** you could check this essay for me?* However, as J.R. pointed out, in your original sentence **if** should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

A more formal construction than just leaving out the if is "Do you think that you could check this essay for me?"  If you leave "that" out, it is implied, hence the informal flavor.  The reason for "do you think that" and "I was wondering if" (more formal would be "I was wondering whether") has to do with the different subjects.  In the first case, you are asking another person what he thinks.  The presumption is that he knows what he thinks.  In the second case, you are expressing your awareness of two possibilities, that he can't help or that he can, and you would like to know if (whether) the desired possibility is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

One rule of thumb in assessing grammar is if you find yourself struggling over a particular *word,* that word usually isn't the problem. It's the broader sentence. On that basis, the issue at hand could be overcome with a simpler construct. As a result, I'd respectfully offer the following rewrite:

```
"Could you check this essay for me?"
```

This construct eliminates all the subjective reinterpretation about who is thinking what, or assumptions about what someone does or doesn't know.